# Determine normal and sheer stresses in a sphere

Tags: classical-mechanics

$3D$ state of stress at point $(1, 1, -2)$ within a body relative to coordinate axis $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is given by

$$ 
 \begin{matrix}
        2 & 3.5 & 2.5 \\
        3 & 0 & -1.5 \\
        2.5 & -1.5 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}   MPa
 $$

Asked to determine the normal and shear stresses at the point and on the surface of an internal sphere whose equation is $$ x_1^2 + (x_2 - 2)^2 + x_3^2 = 6$$

I have the normal $$  \frac {1} {\sqrt 6} (e_1 - e_2 -2e_3)$$

solving I get $$
t_n = \frac {1} {\sqrt 6} (-6.5e_1 + 6.5e_2 + 2e_3)
$$

and I get  $$ \sigma_n = -\frac {17} { 6} $$

How do I find $$ \sigma_s $$ the answer for it is supposed to be $8.67$ MPa but I don't seem to get that.

Edit:

So for the stress, I used

$$ \sigma_s = \sqrt{ |t(n)|^2 - \sigma_n^2} $$

$$ |t(n)^2| = \frac {1} {\sqrt 6} \sqrt{((-6.5)^2 + 6.5^2 + 2^2)} = 3.8405 $$

SO,

$$ \sigma_s =  \sqrt{((3.8405)^2 - (- \frac {17}{6} )^2 } = 2.5927 MPa $$

But the answer is supposed to be $8.67$ MPa

Comment: Please show calculation in symbolic form to trace error.

Comment: Edited the question with what I've tried